# html - font family does not change in the text

Tags: html, css, fonts

**change this text :**

**to**

For all the good times

i try with font family but not working

```css
.custom-font{
font-family: 'SF Pro Display', sans-serif !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-font">    </div>
```

Comment: Insert your html and css code.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use `@font-face` i think, importing the font of your choice if you wish

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded your font using `<link>` or is it local?
If it's local - add `@font face` to your css like this:

@font-face {
font-family:'your font name';
src:url(../path to font) format("font format"),url(../path to font) format("font format");
}

Change name, paths and format accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Apple fonts don't work exactly like Google fonts. This article explains the issue and a potential workaround.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-apples-new-san-francisco-font-on-a-webpage-using-css/

Answer (score -1):

To change the font, you have to set the "font-family" CSS property of the element.
If it's a paragraph, set it to the paragraph. If it's an anchor tag in the paragraph, set it to it.

If you're trying to set a font that is usually available, this method should be enough: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.php

If you're trying to add a custom font, this method is required:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.php

You have to have in mind the font formats, a list and description can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp